# How to pass an instance from a class to another class in Xcode 6.1.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I want to ask about passing an NSMutableArray instance between two of my classes. So, one of the classes is called DovizTableViewController and the other is called AddToDovizViewController.
I have got an instance in DovizTableViewController and it is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayOfDoviz;
```

In the other clas, I want to list all those objects in the array. Well I can again take it from the internet, like I did in the DovizTableViewController, but I don't want to take it from internet again as long as there is a possible way to do it. 
So, specifically and briefly, I want to use that arrayOfDoviz mutable array in my AddToDovizViewController class.

I checked and saw from NSLog output that arrayOfDoviz is correctly built up in its own class, so problem is just about passing.

Thanks in advance!